# Objective-C: Problems in Generating Parentheses

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

Here is the question I met recently.

> Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.
>
> For example, given n = 3, a solution set is:
>
> ```
> "((()))", "(()())", "(())()", "()(())", "()()()"
> ```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)generateParentheses:(int)n{
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    [self generateParentheses:@"" open:0 close:0 pairs:i];
  }
}

- (void)generateParentheses:(NSString *)output open:(int)open close:(int)close pairs:(int)pairs{

if ((open == pairs) && (close == pairs)) {
    NSLog(@"%@",output);
}
else {
    if (open < pairs) {
        output = [output stringByAppendingString:@"("];
        [self generateParentheses:output open:open+1 close:close pairs:pairs];
    }
    
    if (close < open) {
        output = [output stringByAppendingString:@")"];
        [self generateParentheses:output open:open close:close+1 pairs:pairs];
    }
  }
}
```

here is the result when n =2

```
()
(())
(()()
```

when n = 3 ,there are lots of non-well-formed parentheses.
when I use debug,I found that when open=1,close =0,the output is @"((".It was surprised and I didn't know why. Why isn't it @"("?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `open < pairs` and `close < open` in your function, then you modify `output` in the first conditional expression (you append "(") before you reach the second.

To fix this, just get rid of the assignments to `output` and put `[output stringByAppendingString:@"("]` directly in the method call.